# How to access specific HTML links directly via an XPath query

Tags: xml, r, xpath

I'd like to write an XPath query that returns the links from **only part** of a node set. The set is in `//pre[2]`, but to me it seems like it doesn't belong there as it is difficult to access the values cleanly.

The html doc can be imported into R with the following code.

```
library(XML)
doc <- htmlParse("http://www.retrosheet.org/game.htm", isURL = TRUE)
```

`doc` has these attributes, among other non-relevant ones.

```
(s <- summary(doc)$nameCounts)[s > 1]
#
#   a   li   br   ul    b    p  pre   hr   h2 meta 
# 436   50   25   12    7    7    7    6    2    2
```

I want to gather all the `href` links that end in `eve.zip`, **but not those that are `seve.zip`**. I have the desired result with the following code.  But it seems clunky and I'd like to see if we can improve it.

```
xx <- doc["//body/pre[2]/node()[text()]"]
m <- match("b", vapply(xx, xmlName, "")) - 1L
files <- basename(unlist(lapply(xx[1:m], xmlGetAttr, "href")))
summary(files)
#  Length     Class      Mode 
#      86 character character
```

The issue is that `seve.zip` and `eve.zip` are in the same node set, separated by a `<br/>`.  I'm trying to get all the `//pre/a/@href` such that the name of the section is **"Regular Season Event Files"**. But I do not want the section **"Regular Season Event Files by Decade"**.

I know I can just use `getHTMLLinks()` and remove the unwanted links but I'd also like to see if I can learn something new too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) to check the `href` attribute value:

```
//body/pre[2]//a[contains(@href, "eve.zip") and not contains(@href, "seve.zip")]
```

<sub>Tried it using chrome developer tools - got 86 links.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I fiddled around with `contains()` as well.  Is there an xpath function for exact string matching?

Comment: @RichardScriven yup, e.g. `//body/pre[2]//a[@href = "value"]`.

Comment: The full story is that I'm running this over three index sites. Each one has a slightly different structure and I'm using `sprintf()` to get the strings like "eve.zip" into the queries. I'd like to keep the conditional statements to a minimum but maybe I just need to forget that theory

Comment: @RichardScriven the problem is that I can only help with "keep the logic in the XPath" style approach here, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using XPath 2.0 you might be able to use end-with()

```
//body/pre[2]//a[ends-with(@href, 'eve.zip')]
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort. It looks like the xpath functionality might be whatever was offered in libxml and libxml2. But I'm not exactly sure.